# A serializer is not compatible to the actual key type (key type: java.lang.String)

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I was trying to join stream with GlobaKTable, getting the serialization issue.
Joining productStream of `KStream<String,String>` with productTable is `GlobalKTable<String,Product>`
(here Product is a AVRO message)
Below piece of code is doing the join,

```
KStream<String, Product> detailedProductStream = productStream.join(
                productTable,
                (productStreamKey, productStreamValue) -> productStreamValue,
                (productStreamValue, productTableValue) ->  productTableValue
);
```

Defined SpecificAvroSerde for Avro message and Serdes.String() for String type message. I am getting below exception. Any clue? Thanks

```
Exception in thread "web-click-charts-a086d30c-5f8d-4e1f-8e3e-ab4b2ac8f03a-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Exception caught in process. taskId=0_0, processor=KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000006, topic=PRODUCT-CURRENT, partition=0, offset=2, stacktrace=org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: A serializer (org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer) is not compatible to the actual key type (key type: java.lang.String). Change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters.
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.StateSerdes.rawKey(StateSerdes.java:175)
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredWindowStore.keyBytes(MeteredWindowStore.java:222)
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredWindowStore.fetch(MeteredWindowStore.java:167)
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl$WindowStoreReadWriteDecorator.fetch(ProcessorContextImpl.java:547)
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamKStreamJoin$KStreamKStreamJoinProcessor.process(KStreamKStreamJoin.java:94)
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:117)
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:201)
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:180)
```

Serdes defined as below

```
Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<>();
props.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://localhost:8081");

SpecificAvroSerde<Product> productSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();
productSerde.configure(props, false);

Serde stringSerde = Serdes.String();

GlobalKTable<String, Product> productTable = builder.globalTable("TOPIC-1",
                Consumed.with(stringSerde, productSerde));
KStream<String, String> productStream = builder.stream("TOPIC-2",
        Consumed.with(stringSerde, stringSerde));
```

Answer (score 2):

How/where did you specify the serdes? Your code snippet does not show this part.

However, the stack trace indicate that the issue is not with a stream-globalTable join, but with a windowed stream-stream join (the stacktrace shows `KStreamKStreamJoin`) and the error message shows that `ByteArraySerializer` is used for a String key.

Comment: I cannot spot any issue in your code snipped. However, I believe that the shared stack trace does not belong the the code snippet you shared, but your program contains a stream-stream join that is causing the issue.

Comment: I can share the GitHub link

Comment: I had the same issue. After reading @MatthiasJ.Sax's answer, I realized that I forget to specify serdes for stream-stream join. After specifying them, everything was fine.
I used StreamJoined type. 
ex: StreamJoined.with(AppSerdes.String(), AppSerdes.PaymentRequest(), AppSerdes.PaymentConfirmation())